# How to read the database table name of a Model instance?

Tags: django

Given a model's instance object, how can I get the database table's name?

I don't want to specify names explicitly in the Meta class.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Found the answer myself: the _meta attribute of an instance has the information:

```
model_instance._meta.db_table
```

Comment: this is quite weird that Model's table name accessible from protected attribute `_meta::Options`

Comment: @Alex-Bogdanov: the `_meta` property is not protected. It is a documented part of the public API. It is prefixed with the leading underscore to avoid conflicts with names that people may actually want to use on their models.

Comment: If you would like to, create a property method to return it...

`@property`
    `def table_name(self):`
        `return self._meta.db_table`