# How can I sort by the id of a ManyToManyField in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, sql-order-by, manytomanyfield

I've got a ManyToManyField in a user object and it's used to map the users that user is following. I'm trying to show a subset list of who they have most recently followed. Is there a trick in .order_by() that will allow me to sort by the id of the ManyToManyField? The data is there, right?

```
# (people the user is following)
following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="following", blank=True)

theuser.following.filter(user__is_active=True).order_by("user__id")
```

That will give me a list of the users the user is following but ordered by when they joined. I want the order of the following list to be in order of when the user followed them.

Comment: Interesting/strange question. The id field of the intermediate table used by ManyToMany to do the join is interesting because ... ?

Comment: @peter i think the id in that table should show the order of the relationships made so he can do his "you recently followed:" idea.

Comment: @Brandon H, Exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 10):

In fact (at least in Django 1.10), you don't need to use the `extra` feature but instead can just order by the field directly. Just use the automatically created through table name followed by ".id" as an argument to `order_by`.  E.g.

`pizza.toppings.all().order_by('appname_pizza_toppings.id')`

`article.tags.all().order_by('appname_article_tags.id')`

For this particular question:

`theuser.following.filter(user__is_active=True)\
    .order_by("appname_user_user_following.id")`

Many other solutions suggest creating a custom through table and adding a field but if you just want to sort by the id of the automatically generated through table then this is not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Tested with `Django 1.11.10`.

You don't have to hardcode the relationship table name ([How to read the database table name of a Model instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233045/how-to-read-the-database-table-name-of-a-model-instance)).

So an update on @Ry4an Brase's answer can look like

```
recently_followed = '-{}.id'.format(theuser.following.through._meta.db_table)  
theuser.following.filter(user__is_active=True).order_by(recently_followed)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks @Dušan Maďar

Answer (score 5):

I just found a way to do this without having to create a class for the relationship.  It relies on the `extra` feature that lets you add additional columns to output.  In your example it would look like:

```
theuser.following.filter(user__is_active=True)\
    .extra(select={'creation_seq': 'appname_user_user_following.id'})\
    .order_by("creation_seq")
```

Notice that `appname_user_user_following` is the name of the relationship table Django creates under the covers.  It's deterministic and something you can get and set via meta-mechanisms, but it's pretty much safe to hardcode.

Here's an example of the SQL that's being created under the covers with fake table and columns names:

```
SELECT (appname_user_user_following.id) AS `creation_seq`, `appname_user`.`id`
FROM `appname_user` INNER JOIN `appname_user_user_following` ON
(`appname_user`.`id` = `appname_user_user_following`.`user_id`) WHERE
`appname_user_user_following`.`user_followed_id` = 1  ORDER BY `creation_seq` ASC';
```

Comment: That worked for me. You should put the code after 'select' into braces, as it requires a dict.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you can achieve this with a regular `ManytoManyField`. You could try defining the intermediate model explicitly.

**nb: Untested code!**

```
class Person(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class FollowerRelationship(models.Model)
    follower = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name = following_set)
    following = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name = follower_set)
```

You can then create following relationships in the shell as follows.

```
# Create Person objects
>>> a = Person(name="Alice")
>>> a.save()
>>> b = Person(name="Bob")
>>> b.save()
>>> c = Person(name="Chris")
>>> c.save()

# Let Alice follow Chris and Bob 
>>> FollowerRelationship.objects.create(follower=a, following=c)
>>> FollowerRelationship.objects.create(follower=a, following=b)
```

You can create a queryset of `FollowerRelationship` objects where Alice is the follower, ordered by the id of the join table, with the line:

```
>>> qs = FollowerRelationship.objects.filter(follower=a).order_by('id')
>>> [fr.following for fr in qs]
```

Note that you have to loop through the `FollowerRelationship` objects, to get the 'followed' `Person` in the relationship.

You may also want to look at [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) in the Django docs, which describes how to specify the intermediate model in a many-to-many relationship.